# Jquery inArray always returns true

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

The `$.inArray` is always returning true for my user groups check

The specific code is in the `run` function and `checkUserCondition` function.

If you run the program it will display a message with the counts.

Click 'Enter Spins' then click 'Toggle Numberpad' then add the number 8

The user groups register as 8 in group 1,2,3,4,5 and in group 5,6,7,8

Why does `$.inArray()` behave that way?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .bntcal {
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     margin: 10px;
    }
    .bntcaladd {
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     margin: 10px;
    }
    
    .bntshow{
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     margin: 5px;
     width: 10%;
    }
    .spanhide {
     display: none;
    }
    .bell {
     float:left;
     display: none;
    }
    
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var wheel0 = [37,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26];
    var wheel00 = [37,28,9,26,30,11,7,20,32,17,5,22,34,15,3,24,36,13,1,38,27,10,25,29,12,8,19,31,18,6,21,33,16,4,23,35,14,2];
    var wheel = wheel00;
    var wColor = "";
    var numbers = [];
    var color = [];
    
    
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
     // --- Menu Buttons
        $("#enterSpins").click(function(){
      $("#divSpins").show();
      $("#divAlerts").hide();
            $("#divHowTo").hide();
        });
     
     $("#setAlert").click(function(){
      $("#divAlerts").show();
      $("#divSpins").hide();
            $("#divHowTo").hide();
        });
     
     $("#howTo").click(function(){
      $("#divHowTo").show();
      $("#divSpins").hide();
            $("#divAlerts").hide();
     
     });
     
     // ---- Sub Buttons
     $("#enterPad").click(function(){
      $("#showSpinsPad").toggle();
      $("#clearBox").toggle();
      $("#clearBox1").toggle();
      if(!$("#showSpinsPad").is(":hidden"))
      {
       $("#spins").prop("disabled", true)
      }
      else
      {
       $("#spins").prop("disabled", false)
      }
      
        }); 
     
     $(".bntcal").click(function(){
      $("#currentSpin").text($("#currentSpin").text()+$(this).val())
      if ($("#currentSpin").text().length > 2)
      {
       $("#currentSpin").text($(this).val())
      }    
     });
      
     
     $("#clear").click(function(){
      $("#currentSpin").text("")
        });
     
     $("#add").click(function(){
     
      getWheel()
      currentSpin = $("#currentSpin").text()
      if(currentSpin.length > 0)
      {
       if ($("#spins").val().length > 0)
       {
        $("#spins").val($("#spins").val() + ", ");
       }
       if(parseInt(currentSpin)<37)
       {
        $("#spins").val($("#spins").val() + currentSpin);
       }
       if(parseInt(currentSpin) == 37)
       {
        $("#spins").val($("#spins").val() + "0");
       }
       if(parseInt(currentSpin) == 38)
       {
        $("#spins").val($("#spins").val() + "00");
       }
       if(parseInt(currentSpin)>38)
       {
        $("#spins").val($("#spins").val() + "0");
       }
    
       $("#currentSpin").text("") 
      }
      
      var n = GetUserNumbers();
      run(n)
        });
     
     $("#undo").click(function(){
      var n = GetUserNumbers();
      
      if (n.length>0)
      {
       n.pop();
      }
      $("#spins").val(n)
      run(n)
        });
     
     $("#clean").click(function(){
      $("#spins").val("")
        });
     
     $("#run").click(function(){
      var n = GetUserNumbers();
      run(n)
        });
     
    });
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // --------------------- FUNCTIONS -------------------------------
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    
    function run(n)
    {
     
     $("#alert").text("")
    
     // Evens
     var conditions = ['color[n] == "red"','color[n] == "black"','n%2 == 0 && n<37','n%2 == 1 && n<37','n > 18 && n<37','n < 19 && n>0']
     var checklocation = ['Red','Black','Even','Odd','High','Low']
     var idWins = "#evenwin"
     var idLosses = "#evenloss"
     checkCondition(n, conditions, checklocation, idWins, idLosses)
    
     // Dozens
     var conditions = ['n%3 == 1 && n<37','n%3 == 2 && n<37','n%3 == 0 && n<37','n>=1 && n<=12','n>=13 && n<=24','n>=25 && n<=36']
     var checklocation = ['Row 1 [1,2,3..]','Row 2 [2,3,4..]','Row 2 [3,6,9..]','Dozen 1 [1-12]','Dozen 1 [13-24]','Dozen 1 [25-36]']
     var idWins = "#dozenwin"
     var idLosses = "#dozenloss"
     checkCondition(n, conditions, checklocation, idWins, idLosses)
     
     // User Groups
     var groups = $("#usergroup1").val().split('-')
     var userNumbers = []
     for(var i=0; i<groups.length; i++)
     {
      userNumbers.push(groups[i].split(','))
     }
     var idWins = "#userwin1"
     var idLosses = "#userloss1"
     checkUserCondition(n, checklocation, idWins, idLosses, userNumbers)
     
    }
    
    function checkUserCondition(n, checklocation, idWins, idLosses, arr)
    {
     var check = function(n, a){ if($.inArray(n, a)){ return true; } else { return false; }}
     
     for(var ia=0; ia<arr.length; ia++)
     {
      var wins = parseInt(0)
      var losses = parseInt(0)
      wins = checkUserWins(n, check,arr[ia])
      losses = checkUserLosses(n, check,arr[ia])
      alert(arr[ia])
      $("#alert").append("note User Group: "+arr[ia]+" Win count: "+wins+"<br/>")
      //if(wins >= $(idWins).val()) { $("#alert").append(checklocation[i]+" loses "+wins+" times in a rows.<br/>")}
      //if(losses >= $(idLosses).val()) { $("#alert").append(checklocation[i]+" loses "+losses+" times in a rows.<br/>")}
     }
     
    }
    
    function checkCondition(n, conditions, checklocation, idWins, idLosses)
    {
     for(var i=0; i<conditions.length; i++)
     {
      var wins = parseInt(0)
      var losses = parseInt(0)
      var check = function(n){ if(eval(conditions[i])){ return true; } else { return false; }}
      wins = checkWins(n, check)
      
      $("#alert").append("note: "+checklocation[i]+" Condition: "+conditions[i]+"  Win count: "+wins+"<br/>")
      
      losses = checkLosses(n, check)
      //if(wins >= $(idWins).val()) { $("#alert").append(checklocation[i]+" loses "+wins+" times in a rows.<br/>")}
      //if(losses >= $(idLosses).val()) { $("#alert").append(checklocation[i]+" loses "+losses+" times in a rows.<br/>")}
     }
     
    }
    
    function checkUserWins(n, condition, arr)
    {
     var wins = parseInt(0);
     for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++)
     {
      if(condition(parseInt(n[i]),arr))
      {
       wins += 1 
      }
      else
      {
       wins = 0
      } 
     }
     
     return wins 
    }
    
    function checkUserLosses(n, condition, arr)
    {
     var losses = parseInt(0);
     for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++)
     {
      if(condition(n[i],arr))
      {
       losses = 0
      }
      else
      {
       losses += 1
      }
     }
     return losses
    }
    
    function checkWins(n, condition)
    {
     var wins = parseInt(0);
     for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++)
     {
      if(condition(n[i]))
      {
       wins += 1 
      }
      else
      {
       wins = 0
      } 
     }
     
     return wins 
    }
    
    function checkLosses(n, condition)
    {
     var losses = parseInt(0);
     for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++)
     {
      if(condition(n[i]))
      {
       losses = 0
      }
      else
      {
       losses += 1
      }
     }
     return losses
    }
    
    $.fn.multiline = function(text){
        this.text(text);
        this.html(this.html().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>'));
        return this;
    }
    
    
    function getWheel()
    {
     if($("input[name=wheel]:checked").val()=="0")
     {
      wheel = wheel0
     }
     else
     {
      wheel = wheel00
     }
     color = GetColor(wheel)
    }
    
    function reset()
    {
     evenwins = parseInt(0);
    }
    function GetUserNumbers()
    {
     var n = $("#spins").val().split(",");
     
     for(var x=0; x<n.length; x++)
     {
      if(n[x].trim() == "0")
      {
       n[x] = "37";
      }
      if(n[x].trim() == "00")
      {
       n[x] = "38";
      }
      n[x] = parseInt(n[x].trim());
     }
     return n;
    }
    
    function GetColor(wheel)
    {
     var color = Array();
     if(wheel.length==37)
     {
      color[1] = "red";
      color[2] = "black";
      color[3] = "red";
      color[4] = "black";
      color[5] = "red";
      color[6] = "black";
      color[7] = "red";
      color[8] = "black";
      color[9] = "red";
      color[10] = "black";
      color[11] = "black";
      color[12] = "red";
      color[13] = "black";
      color[14] = "red";
      color[15] = "black";
      color[16] = "red";
      color[17] = "black";
      color[18] = "red";
      color[19] = "red";
      color[20] = "black";
      color[21] = "red";
      color[22] = "black";
      color[23] = "red";
      color[24] = "black";
      color[25] = "red";
      color[26] = "black";
      color[27] = "red";
      color[28] = "black";
      color[29] = "black";
      color[30] = "red";
      color[31] = "black";
      color[32] = "red";
      color[33] = "black";
      color[34] = "red";
      color[35] = "black";
      color[36] = "red";
      color[37] = "green";
     }
     if(wheel.length==38)
     {
      color[1] = "red";
      color[2] = "black";
      color[3] = "red";
      color[4] = "black";
      color[5] = "red";
      color[6] = "black";
      color[7] = "red";
      color[8] = "black";
      color[9] = "red";
      color[10] = "black";
      color[11] = "black";
      color[12] = "red";
      color[13] = "black";
      color[14] = "red";
      color[15] = "black";
      color[16] = "red";
      color[17] = "black";
      color[18] = "red";
      color[19] = "red";
      color[20] = "black";
      color[21] = "red";
      color[22] = "black";
      color[23] = "red";
      color[24] = "black";
      color[25] = "red";
      color[26] = "black";
      color[27] = "red";
      color[28] = "black";
      color[29] = "black";
      color[30] = "red";
      color[31] = "black";
      color[32] = "red";
      color[33] = "black";
      color[34] = "red";
      color[35] = "black";
      color[36] = "red";
      color[37] = "green";
      color[38] = "green";
     }
     return color;
    }
    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Toggle Displays</br><br/>
    <div >
    <button class="bntshow" id="enterSpins">Enter Spins</button><br/>
    <button class="bntshow" id="setAlert">Set Alerts</button><br/>
    <button class="bntshow" id="howTo">How To</button><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="wheel" value="0">0 Wheel<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="wheel" value="00" checked>00 Wheel<br/>
    </div><br/>
    <div id="alert"></div>
    <hr>
    
    
    <!-- Enter Spins -->
    <span class="spanhide" id="divSpins">
    <button class="bntcaladd" id="enterPad">Toggle Numberpad</button><br/>
    <br/>
    
    <span class="spanhide" id='showSpinsPad'>
    <br/>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="0">0</button>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="00">00</button><br/>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="3">3</button><br/>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="4">4</button>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="5">5</button>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="6">6</button><br/>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="7">7</button>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="8">8</button>
    <button class="bntcal" id="calculator" value="9">9</button><br/>
    <button class="bntcaladd" id="clear">Clear</button>
    <button class="bntcaladd" id="add">ADD</button><span id="currentSpin"></span>
    <br/>
    <button class="bntcaladd" id="undo">Undo</button><br/>
    <span id="currentSpin"></span>
    <br/>
    </span>
    <span id="clearBox">Enter roulette numbers separated by a comma</span><br/>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="spins"></textarea><br/><br/>
    <span id="clearBox1">
    <button id="clean">Clear Box</button>
    <button id="run">Run</button>
    </span>
    
    </span>
    
    <!-- Set Alerts -->
    <span class="spanhide" id="divAlerts">
    <h2>Evens</h2>
    <input type="text" id="evenwin" value="2"> Wins in a row<br>
    <input type="text" id="evenloss" value="6"> Losses in a row<br>
    <br><br>
    <h2>Dozens</h2>
    <input type="text" id="dozenwin" value="6"> Wins in a row<br>
    <input type="text" id="dozenloss" value="6"> Losses in a row<br>
    <br><br>
    <h2>User Group</h2>
    <input type="text" id="usergroup1" value="1,2,3,4,5-5,6,7,8"> Number Group<br>
    <input type="text" id="userwin1" value="1"> Wins in a row<br>
    <input type="text" id="userloss1" value="6"> Losses in a row<br>
    <br><br>
    
    </span>
    
    <!-- How To -->
    <span class="spanhide" id="divHowTo">
    How To
    </span>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Why does the InArray always return true for my user groups?

Comment: Could you please post only the part of function and a simple few lines code where you are actually having the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer [(from jQuery documentation)](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) :

> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), to check for the presence of value within array, you need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.

`JavaScript` treats `-1` as `truthy` and `0` as `falsy`. If the number you are looking for is not in the `array` it returns -1 treated as `true`.

For more on boolean in JavaScript refer to those link: [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Boolean)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  
  var bool = $.inArray(8, arr);
  
  console.log(bool)
  
  if(bool)
    console.log('bool is true')
  else
    console.log('bool is false');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I expected inArray to return true and I wanted the index it was a different method.

Comment: It kinda return `true`, just not in a form that we are used to :P  One thing you can do to prevent using `truthy` and `falsy` variable is to test if they are `boolean` first using either `$.type(var) == 'boolean'` or `typeof var === 'boolean`

Answer (score 1):

If something exists in the array it returns it's index, if not it returns `-1`

```
if($.inArray(object, array) != -1){
  // In array
} else {
  // Not in array
}
```